# SpringBoot JPA entity ignore timezone while save date to PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

So, i have a table with String / Varchar column type in PostgreSQL database.

And, my spring boot entity for this column :

```
@Column(name = "pickup_schedule")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date customPickupTm;
```

And then, my table saving the data of customPickupTm below :

[wrong formatted time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1y5d.png)

But i only need insert to the column with format HH:mm:ss , not with +07

Any solution to remove that +07?

i'm already check & debug the final value that set to the customPickupTm variable with HH:mm:ss format

[debugged variable value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgxvE.png)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: Hi & Welcome! Are you sure it is "varchar column"? What is your computer/server time zone, what is db TZ?

Comment: @xerx593 yes im sure, i need to keep the column type to varchar for some condition needs, my db Asia/Bangkok

Comment: (wouldn't be "string column" less confusing/offer more control!?;)

Comment: @xerx593 i know, but if i change to other, it will need some major changes :') so many logic depend on this entity

Comment: I'm curious on what will happen and what you expect to happen when you try to read back those database values. Dates are built based on the absolute millisecond value returned, so it will appear different for everyone who reads it, and entirely depend on the time within the database itself. If all you want is a string based 'relative' time, you'll need to write your own converter for it to turn your Date into a String and back.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
@Column(name = "pickup_schedule", columnDefinition = "timestampt with time zone not null", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date customPickupTm;
```

Comment: nothing changes, still the same value